# SPFile.OpenBinary method from URL

Tags: 2010, development, url

I would like to use this method to get the byte information from a document based on its URL so that I can copy it to a new location. 
I have only seen examples using `file.OpenBinary();` where file is simply used within a `foreach` loop through all the files in a library. I have a list that I use as a sort of "queue" which adds an item with its source url in one column and the destination url in another. How can I essentially do something like:

```
file = "mysite.com/file2.docx"
byte[] myFile = file.OpenBinary();
SPFile copiedFile = someLibrary.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.Url), myFile);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SPWeb.GetFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063.aspx) method to get the SPFile object from string URL.

Then you can use [SPFile.OpenBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.openbinary.aspx) method and so on..

Of course you will need SPWeb object of the site where the file exists..